# Reverse of a number using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, reverse

The reverse of the number is getting printed many times. How do I print it just once?

For example, if I give input as `1234` then the output is coming out as `4321 4321 4321 4321`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//function declaration
void printReverse(int);

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tThis program prints reverse of a given number");
    printf("\nEnter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    //if someone enters 0
    if(n==0)
    {
        printf("%d",n);
        exit(0);
    }
    //function call
    printReverse(n);
    
    return 0;
}

void printReverse(int n)
{
    static int rev=0; 
    
    //base case
    if(n) 
    {
        int rem = n % 10;      
        rev = rev*10 + rem; 
        printReverse(n/10); 
    }
    printf("%d ",rev);
    
    
}
```

Comment: You should not use the static variable in the recursive function. You should separate the calculation of the reversed value from the printing.

Answer (score 0):

The way your `printReverse` function is currently written, the last line (`printf("%d ",rev);`) will *always* be executed whenever the function is called, because there is no code path through the function that skips that line. So, when the recursion has reached the point where the given argument is zero, you will get that line being called each time on the 'rewind' of the stacked, recursive calls (once for each digit in the initial `n`).

To fix this, you can either enclose that `printf` line in an `else` block:

```c
void printReverse(int n)
{
    static int rev = 0;
    if (n) {
        int rem = n % 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + rem;
        printReverse(n / 10);
    }
    else { // Only print the result when we're finished (n = 0):
        printf("%d\n", rev);
    }
}
```

Or, accomplishing much the same thing, add a `return` statement after you make the recursive call:

```c
void printReverse(int n)
{
    static int rev = 0;
    if (n) {
        int rem = n % 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + rem;
        printReverse(n / 10);
        return; // Don't print on the rewind from recursion
    }
    printf("%d\n", rev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**C Program to reverse a given number using Recursive function**

> *based on https://beginnersbook.com/2014/06/c-program-to-reverse-a-given-number-using-recursive-function/*

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int sum=0, rem;

int reverse_function(int num) {
  if(num) {
    rem=num%10;
    sum=sum*10+rem;
    reverse_function(num/10);
  }
  else
    return sum;
  return sum;
}

int main() {
  int num,reverse_number;

  //Take the number as an input from user
  printf("Enter any number:");
  scanf("%d",&num);

  //Calling user defined function to perform reverse
  reverse_number=reverse_function(num);
  printf("The reverse of entered number is :%d",reverse_number);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]